# XSLT recursion and 2 parameters

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble getting XML data to format properly in HTML via XSLT. Here is how data is received:

```
    This is some text. <p> 
    This is more text. <p> 
    This is even more text. <p>
    <a href=www.google.com>Google's website</a> <p> 
    Return to my website.
```

So I have recursion (I think that is what's used in this case) setup. It will create a new paragraph for each p tag, and remove the p tag on our website. Here's the code:

```
<xsl:template name="replace_p">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;P&gt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;P&gt;')"/>
             <br/><br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace_p">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&lt;P&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

This works great...except when we have links. I want users to be able to click on the link rather than see the a href tag and code. Only problem is... how do I do this when the replace p template running. My attempt (I feel like I have the right idea, although probably not close):

```
    <xsl:template name="replace_p">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, '&lt;P&gt;')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring-before($text, '&lt;P&gt;') and substring-before($text, '&lt;a href=')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&lt;a href='), '&gt;')"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace_p">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&lt;P&gt;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring-before($text, '&lt;P&gt;')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;P&gt;')"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace_p">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&lt;P&gt;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I put the test of p tag and a href tag test first, because I want it to check both before going to the next when statement. BUT... I don't know if that's how it necessarily works. Will it check the first p tag and a href tag before going to the next when statement?

I also know I need to create an a tag and an href attribute, but i'd like to work on getting the right data to show up first. :)

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the`<p>` tag  means in HTML and how it's used? Probably ought to start there.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are trying to transform illegal xml by treating it as text.

If you are processing plain text, there are other techniques better suited to the job than xslt. Do not use xslt if you're not transforming (legal) xml, it makes no sense.

If you really want to use xslt, make sure you have legal xml first. Then, all is easy using templates and selectors and all the niceties of xslt and xpath.

Just for fun, see the introduction of [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx) to understand what it is you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's rough, but I needed that. I'm new to web development, so my questions or way of thinking might come off wrong. The data I receive comes in with the <p> tags, so it isn't plain text coming in but rather HTML? I'm converting the html text with xslt. I should be converting the html to xml ... then use xslt to transform it?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
<xsl:call-template name="replace_p"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace_p">
 <xsl:param name="text" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('Try2.txt'), '\r?\n')"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="$text">

 <p>
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="(substring-after(normalize-space(.), '&lt;a href=') != '')">
 <xsl:element name="a">
 <xsl:attribute name="href">
 <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://', substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;a href='), '&gt;'))"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&gt;'), '&lt;/a&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
 </xsl:element></xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="((substring-before(normalize-space(.), '&lt;p&gt;')) != '')">
 <xsl:value-of select="(substring-before(normalize-space(.), '&lt;p&gt;'))"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
 </p>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is 
[code]

```
<xml>
<p>This is some text. </p>
<p>This is more text. </p>
<p>This is even more text. </p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google's website</a></p>
<p>Return to my website.</p>
</xml>
```

[/code]